# How to incorporate FastAPI authentication with a simple frontend (no frameworks)?

Tags: javascript, authentication, frontend, backend, fastapi

I've been trying to get my head around this for hours. The tutorials on YouTube just cover the back-end and they use the /docs page to show that it works but I can't figure out how to translate it to a front-end... (front-end/back-end work is relatively new to me).

FastAPI have documentation where they create the backend for authentication:

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/

However, how can one make a simple front-end for it with vanilla JS or Jquery?

Just hearing some thoughts on this would be very helpful as I'd really like to learn how I can do this so I get what's going on behind the scenes.

My goals:

- Have a path that is secured (can't access without authentication)
- Let users enter username/password on the home page (not secured)
- Then after this, allow the rest of the pages to become accessible to this user.

Pseudo Code

```
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def form():
    return """
           <input type=password>
           <button onClick="submit()">       
           <script>
               request = xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer MYTOKEN")
               // Here load secured page with these headers and access it.
           </script>    
           """
```

Comment: You'll have to have logic in your frontend that retrieves a magic user token from your authentication endpoint, stores it as a cookie or (usually) in local storage, and then retrieves that token and includes it in every request after that to prove that you have access to any given resources. When you're using Javascript like this it won't usually map to a "page", but to a "resource" - i.e. "can you get details about this user" or "can you get the list of recent articles".

Comment: @MatsLindh I have that part, I'm just really stuck on the bit where I "include it in every request after". Is that bit written on the client's side or server's side? If so, do you have an example of it please?

Comment: It needs to be in your client code - for example you could enclose your requests in a custom function that creates and makes the xhr call, and in that function add the custom header as necessary. The simplest way would be to have something like `getXhrRequest` that have a preconfigured object that you can use to make the request.

Answer (score 0):

The token can be set from Response.set_cookie(key="foo", value="bar") I think.
And afterwards it is sent with every request in the request header.

Request.get_cookie(key="foo")